# How to set the oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible property

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc, groovy, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g with a Grails 1.3.2 application. I am targeting a legacy schema with all `Date` columns types used where time is stored. I believe I need to set the `oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible` property to `true` somewhere in order to use Groovy's `Sql.rows` instance method (which uses `ResultSet.getObject` under the hood) to get `java.sql.Timestamp` objects with time components preserved instead `java.sql.Date` objects with time component truncated (see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_00)). Where is the right / best place to set / how do I set the `oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible` property in a Grails application?

we use DataSource.groovy for development, and a JBoss JNDI configuration for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the `Sql.rows` / `V8Compatibility` approach and instead am just using a custom function:

```
public static java.sql.Timestamp sqlScalarTimestamp(dataSource, query, params) {
    Sql sql;
    try {
        sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def result = null
        sql.query(query, params) { rs ->
            if(rs.next())
                result = rs.getTimestamp(1)
        }
        return result
    } finally {
        if(sql != null)
            sql.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the development environment I suggest to specify it in DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    // common settings          
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            properties = "oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true"
        }
    }   
}
```

For production you have to put this in the [connection-property](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html) field for the datasource.

Comment: Hmm, testing the development configuration, I set the property, performed a clean, and then ran the app, but the offending value returned from `Sql.rows` is still type `java.sql.Date`...